# compare float and integer variable in bash results change all the time

Tags: bash, variables, compare

I'm trying to evaluate the elements in an array with a float using the following command as an example:

```
sorted=(0 0.0223611 0.977639)
if [[ $(echo "${sorted[-2]} > 0" | bc) ]];then echo 'yes';else echo 'no';fi
```

which will give the right answer 'yes'; however, when I change '0' to '0.8',

```
if [[ $(echo "${sorted[-2]} > 0.8" | bc) ]];then echo 'yes';else echo 'no';fi
```

it still give the same answer 'yes',which is incorrect.

After this, if I change the command line to:

```
if [[ $(echo ${sorted[-2]} > 0.8 | bc) ]];then echo 'yes';else echo 'no';fi
```

the answer is 'no', which is correct. But if I change back to 0, the answer is still 'no'.

So every time I add or delete the double quote,the first answer is correct. But it won't change no matter how the float changes afterwards. I'm totally lost what's going on here. Please help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`bc` prints `0` for false and `1` for true. Both `[[ 0 ]]` and `[[ 1 ]]` are true, but you can compare them to 1:

```
if [[ $( bc -l <<< "${sorted[-2]} > 0.8" ) = 1 ]]
```

or use the arithmetic expression in which 0 is false and 1 (or any other number) is true:

```
if (( $( bc -l <<< "${sorted[-2]} > 0.8" ) ))
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know these expressions before. But I have a question here: I noticed there was an answer disappeared now, which is : 

    if [[ "${sorted[-2]}" > 0 ]]

I don't understand why is deleted. Is there a problem with this one? I find it works fine with my data.

Comment: @carolynzy: Using strings for numeric comparison is wrong. `[[ 33 > 4 ]]` is false, `[[ .09 > 0.8 ]]` is true.

Comment: Thank you again! You are so patient! I do need to catch up with the basic knowledge. Transfer from biology background to bioinfo isn't easy!